# How can I use multiple html5qrcode Scanner on one site, for different targets?

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I am using this [Html5-QRCode](https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode) library on my mobile site to fill a single field of a form.

```
$('.qrscan').click(function () {
        scanModal();
});
const html5QrCode = new Html5Qrcode("qr-reader",);
const qrCodeSuccessCallback = (decodedText, decodedResult) => {
    console.log(decodedText);
    html5QrCode.stop();
    $('#scanModal').modal('hide');
};
const config = { fps: 10, qrbox: 250 };
var scanModal = function () {
    $('#scanModal').modal('show');
    html5QrCode.start({ facingMode: "environment" }, config, qrCodeSuccessCallback);
};
```

This works like a charm. I'm having trouble using a scanner for multiple, different fields. What I want to do is to have mutliple input fields with a button next to it. The Button opens the qr-code scanner and on a successfull scan the corresponding field is filled.

**Do i have to create a different instance of the qrcode scanner or can I somehow define a target for the successCallback?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Do i have to create a different instance of the qrcode scanner or can I somehow define a target for the successCallback?

I think you can make do with single instance. You however need to write another global singleton component that is aware of which box is being filled and the callback can just call this form aware component.

```js
interface FormQrScannerMediator {
   // Called when the in focus input id changes.
   void setInfocusInputId(id: string);

   // Called from qrcode scanner
   void onQrcodeScanSuccess(decodedText: string);
}

// TODO: initialised with a class that implements FormQrScannerMediator
const mediator: FormQrScannerMediator;
const html5QrCode = new Html5Qrcode("qr-reader",);
const qrCodeSuccessCallback = (decodedText, decodedResult) => {
    mediator.onQrcodeScanSuccess(decodedText);
    html5QrCode.stop();
    $('#scanModal').modal('hide');
};
// ..rest of code
```